# jQuery 1.7.2 - selector.val() breaks in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have the following block in my HTML

```
<div class="selection">
  <p><input name="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" id="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" type="radio" value="I am solely responsible for the decision">I am solely responsible for the decision </p>   
  <p><input name="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" id="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" type="radio" value="I am partially responsible for or influence the decision">I am partially responsible for or influence the decision </p>
  <p><input name="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" id="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" type="radio" value="I am not involved in the decision">I am not involved in the decision </p>
  <p><input name="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" id="custrecord_npsdtl_decision" type="radio" value="Don't know">Don't know </p>
</div>
```

And a function to check form-progression, based on the option selected, with the following snippet:

```
var decisionmaker = $('#custrecord_npsdtl_decision:checked').val();
if (decisionmaker == elements['customlist_nps_decision'][2] || decisionmaker == elements['customlist_nps_decision'][3]) {
  redirect();
}
```

This works as expected in Chrome, Firefox but was not working in Internet Explorer(8).  Doing some inspection I found that

```
$('#custrecord_npsdtl_decision:checked')
```

returns an object, as expected, but calling val() on the object returns undefined.

I am absolutely bewildered. How do I get the selected option from the radio list in IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ID's must be unique. I'm very surprised that this is working at all in Chrome and Firefox.

Remove the id attributes and select by name.

```
$('input[name="custrecord_npsdtl_decision"]:checked').val();
```

Comment: I see.  Great explanation, wasn't clear from the jquery docs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you shouldnt use the same ID for each radio button and you can use the name selector to get the group selection

```
$('input[name=custrecord_npsdtl_decision]:checked').val();
```